# replace string from specific position until end Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, position

how can I replace a random String like:

2020-02-01T13:49
2020-02-01T04:27
2020-02-01T20:51

from starting with letter 'T'

So from T til the end of string I wanna replace it with T00:00

I have different Datetime Strings, so it should be flexible.

Comment: Could you please share the code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of options:

### `replace`

`replace` with a simple regular expression:

```
result = original.replace(/T.*$/, "T00:00");
```

That says "match T followed by anything through the end of the string".

### `indexOf` and `substring`:

Alternatively, `indexOf` will tell you where the `T` is, then you can use `substring`:

```
const index = original.indexOf("T");
result = original.substring(0, index) + "T00:00";
```

#### `split("T")[0]`

You could also split on the `T` and only use the first string from the array:

```
result = original.split("T") + "T00:00";
```

---

I recommend a good read through [the MDN documentation of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).